# No output from PHP MySQL function array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, output

I have an array with values declared in a while statement at the end of function fetch_conversation_messages in a backend file for a private message system.  However, the array that is revealed is blank (other than the echos and print_rs that I have used for debugging).

I am very new to this forum, PHP and MySQL, so please help me.

Thank you in advance.

```
// Fetches all of the messages in the given converstion.
function fetch_conversation_messages($conversation_id){
    $conversation_id = (int)$conversation_id;

    $sql = "SELECT
  `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
  `conversations_messages`.`message_text`,
  `users`.`user_name`
FROM `conversations_messages`
INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    var_dump($result);
    $messages = array();

    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
            $messages[] = array(
                    'date'          => $row['message_date'],
                    'unread'        => $row['message_unread'],
                    'text'          => $row['message_text'],
                    'user_name'     => $row['user_name'],
            );
      echo mysql_num_rows($result);
                    var_dump($row);

    }
echo count($messages);}
```

Also, there is a foreach error (written below as a comment on the first answer) in view_conversation.page.inc.php, which is this page:

```
    <?php

$errors = array();
$valid_conversation = (isset($_GET['conversation_id']) && validate_conversation_id($_GET['conversation_id']));
if ($valid_conversation === false){
        $errors[] = 'Invalid Conversation ID.';
}
if (isset($_POST['message'])){
        if (empty($_POST['message'])){
                $errors[] = 'You must enter a message.';
        }

        if (empty($errors)){
                add_conversation_message($_GET['conversation_id'], $_POST['message']);
        }
}

if (empty($errors) === false){
        foreach ($errors as $error){
        }
}
echo $error;

if ($valid_conversation){
        /*if (isset($_POST['message'])){
                update_conversation_last_view($_GET['conversation_id']);*/
                $messages = fetch_conversation_messages($_GET['conversation_id']);
                print_r($messages);
        /*}else{
                $messages = fetch_conversation_messages($_GET['conversation_id']);
                update_conversation_last_view($_GET['conversation_id']);
        }*/

}
?>
<a href="index.php?page=inbox">Inbox</a>
<a href="index.php?page=logout">Logout</a>

        <form action="" method="post">
                <p><textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="110"></textarea></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Add Message" /></p>
        </form>

        <?php
        foreach ($messages as $message){
        ?>
        <?php if ($message['unread']) echo 'unread'; ?>
        <p class="name">Username: <?php echo $message['user_name']; ?></p>
        <p class="text">Date: <?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $message['date']); ?></p>
        <p>Message: <?php echo $message['text']; ?></p>

<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Have you tried running your query manually to make sure there actually are results? I mean in phpMyAdmin or similar

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: I have tried, but it relies on so many variables that it is hard to test properly

Comment: I get resource(16) of type (mysql result) 0, I wish to get an array containing 'date', 'unread', 'text', 'user_name'

Comment: `echo $sql; die();` just after where is your query string and copy that query and run manually. is there any results? Additionally, `INNER` join will only effective if there is a match in both tables. And I believe there are no matching records.

Comment: @Bilal so what would you reccomend I use instead - could you give me an example please

Comment: First you need to run your query manually and see how many records are selected.

Comment: I can't because there are several variables in the query that are defined in PHP

Comment: What should I do as an alternative to querying directly?